# PPTx to video (mp4) with varied slide timing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking to convert pptx files to video (preferably mp4) using ffmpeg.
However the other main requirement is to have different show / visual timing of each slide in the video.
Eg: 5 Slide pptx file. Couple of slides have more data so they need to stay bit longer in the video, others have less data so they can be shown for lesser duration. Preferably, ppt animations would also be captured in the video.

Since we have to convert lots of such pptx files we need to automate the entire process using scripts etc. Can't be a manual process. If it's a multi step process then we can write that in scripts to automate all the steps for each file.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83#OfficeVersion=Office365 — there may be a way to automate that, depending on your OS. Or you could export the PPT into images first, then create a slideshow from that. Would be good to know what you have already tried. This site is not really meant for asking others to do the work for you, so please share your research, and a few more details regarding your environment (OS).

Comment: ffmpeg can't read PPTX so this has to be done wiithin PPT.

Comment: We have tried PPTX >> PDF >> JPG >> MP4. Its working but with volumes of data its a really long process. Hence looking for guidance if we can cut short this long chain. @Gyan : request if u can share command for PPT to Video. We will try that. Also how can we retain / add varied slide timing in the Video. Our OS is Linux / CentOS.

Comment: @slhck: Have seen the article u shared...but thats a manual process. We have volume of data , looking for script / automated process.

Comment: PPTX files can be exported to JPEG directly, using PowerPoint. No need to produce PDFs. For quality reasons, I'd use PNG instead of JPEG though. This seems like a quite efficient approach. ffmpeg can read neither PPTX nor PPT directly. For the slide timing, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the URL. We could manage the timing of the JPEG. However, since we have tons of data to be converted in 1000s of PPT(x) so we cant use manual functions of PowerPoint to further convert into JPEG. So far we have automated the process from data to video with multiple steps.. Data >> PPTX >> PDF >> JPEGs >> MP4. Looking forward to shorten the steps from PPT(x) to Video.

Comment: But how can you automate exporting to PDF, while claiming that exporting to JPEG/PNG is not possible automatically? I think you should really [edit] and clarify your question to explain what you have already tried and where you are stuck.